# How do I connect oracle DB with my python script?

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter-notebook, pandasql

I have a requirement to connect oracle DB with python and covert them as Dataframe. Would like to know what are the easy packages available and how to install them ?

I am using Anaconda 3(Python 3.5.2), I tried with cx_oracle but couldn't install because of dependencies. Heard about SQLAlchemy bit not sure how to use it.

Comment: SQLAlchemy doesn't bring its own drivers. You'll still need something like `cx_Oracle`. Can you expand on this statement: "I tried with cx_oracle but couldn't install because of dependencies"?  Fixing those issues is probably the best way to proceed.

Comment: The exact error which occurs is "ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application". I have installed pre-compiled version Cx_oracle.

Comment: At this point I would delete this question and ask a new one about that error. You'll get more eyes on it that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At last it worked after following the below steps,

1.Download and unzip version 12 from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/winsoft-085727.html.
2.Add "ORACLE_HOME" as a Windows environment variable and set its value to ...\instantclient_12_1, (not its containing folder!).
3.Add this same path to the "Path" environment variable.
4.Only now install cx_Oracle.
5.Reboot the system

Thanks much for everyone!

Answer (score 0):

I have experience with SQLAlchemy+MySQL.

From the documentation of [SQLAlchemy](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/engines.html),

`engine = create_engine('oracle://username:password@host:port/database')`
is the connection string.

Where:

`username` = username

`password` = password

`host` = host name/IP e.g.(127.0.0.1)

`port` = port number

`database` = database name

```
engine = create_engine('oracle://username:password@host:port/database')
sql = 'Your SQL query in string.'
df = pd.read_sql(sql,con=engine)
```

This should read the sql response into a dataframe.

Comment: Tried throws an error "No module named 'cx_Oracle'". As I stated before I coudn't install cx_oracle because of dependencies. Pip install or conda install isn't working out.

Comment: @prady, My bad. SQLAlchemy by default is using cx_Oracle.